# getting trouble with CSS in twitter widget using wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a http://4gwirelessforum.intemind.biz/ i used there a plugin twitter widget that showing at the right side name of My LinkedIn Profile i have to manage the profile image I know how to set I just need to give width of its 285px; on  but cant understand where to put it is saying the online url static.licdn.com for css. how can there be possibility to change it.

An early reply will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you don't need to change the image size but whole container's size which is containing that widget part.

go in your style.css or plugin's css(if you know) and add the css of this line in end :

```
.li-profile-container { width:302px !important; }
```

before it was 350px so i have used !important as you don't know about this css location but keep in mind, its work around as m not sure about your site's other css so have this as current solution but also test that it won't affect other css(i think it won't).

Comment: Umesh is my client,

leo it is showing online css static.licdn.com I also dont know from where it is coming.

Comment: that's why i add !important so just copy this code and add in your site style,css. simple